# Using INSERT, SELECT and UPDATE in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data into a table, however I would like to select the ID which is auto incremented when the row is made, and then I would like to set it into a field within another table.

For example

1. INSERT INTO playerdata (Username) VALUES ('%e')
2. SELECT ID FROM playerdata p WHERE Username = '%e' LIMIT 1
3. UPDATE masterdata SET Slot = p.ID

I have been trying to find out a way for a hours now, but still no luck, so if there is a way to do this, please reply with it or if there is an easier way, then please explain. All replies are gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any programming languages or just sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a trigger after insert like this

```
create trigger update_masterdata after insert on playerdata
for each row
begin
  UPDATE masterdata SET Slot = NEW.id;
end/
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6a77/1)

Comment: But I need to use SELECT to gather the ID after the row has been inserted, how would I do this with the trigger?

Comment: Oh you need the ID for something else other than Updating masterdata..then i guess you have to run a query searching for that username.

Comment: No, I mean-.. I need to insert the data into playerdata, then I need to update the masterdata using the new ID created when inserting the data, I am not assuming that "NEW" on the "NEW.id" already does this? It was my mistake

Comment: the NEW.id will be the auto_incremented value that was inserted when an insert was called.

Comment: on the sqlfiddle i set delimiter as /... you'll have to specify your own delimiter or use the appropriate one

Comment: and don't forget the semicolon at the end of update statement

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is a DML trigger upon insert.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it seems like it will do the trick, I will take a look at it and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you only insert 1 rows.

You can try [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function

Comment: I would be able to use this-.. however I am coding for SA-MP using BlueG's MySQL plugin and it doesn't include this function in it, thank you for the help though.